# Reading Chinese characters in R using readChar()

Tags: r

I notice that it is easy to load CSV files containing Chinese characters in R with `read.csv("mydata.csv", encoding="UTF-8")`.

I have **text files** (.txt) which I want to read using `readChar()`. However, `readChar()` does not allow me to specify encoding.

What can I do?

Comment: `?readLines` maybe?

Comment: Thanks, that works!